# Example php to nodejs code of ftp connection with ssl

Tags: node.js, ssl, ftp

I have a code on php with work fine.

```php
$host = 'ftp.someserver.com';
$port = 21;
$pass = 'xxxx';
$user = 'username';

$connect = ftp_ssl_connect($host, $port);
$login = ftp_login($connect, $user, $pass);

if ($login) {
    ftp_pasv($connect, true);
    $list = ftp_mlsd($connect, ".");
    var_dump($list);
}
else {
   exit(error_get_last());
}

ftp_close($connect);
```

Connection from WinSCP  (c# example):

```cs
SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
{
    Protocol = Protocol.Ftp,
    HostName = "ftp.someserver.com",
    UserName = "username",
    Password = "xxxx",
    FtpSecure = FtpSecure.Explicit,
    TlsHostCertificateFingerprint = "dd:70:5c:67:xx:xx:xx:....",
    TimeoutInMilliseconds = 45000,
};

sessionOptions.AddRawSettings("FtpForcePasvIp2", "1");
```

I need to write this on nodejs, tried to use basic-ftp package, but always give error like:

```
SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:
] {
  library: 'SSL routines',
  function: 'ssl3_get_record',
  reason: 'wrong version number',
  code: 'ERR_SSL_WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER'
}
```

**UPD:**

This is example my code on node.js, on my local windows machine i got error like above, on other like this. Not quite understand what is the reason and what needs to be inserted into `secureOptions`, but think it need.

```js
const ftp = require("basic-ftp") 
const config = {
    host: "ftp.someserver.com",
    user: "username",
    password: "xxxx",
    port: 21,
    secure: true,
}

const client = new ftp.Client()
// client.ftp.verbose = true
try {
    await client.access(config)
    console.log(await client.list())
}
catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
}
client.close()
```

Console output (hide some not important details in my opinion):

```
Error [ERR_TLS_CERT_ALTNAME_INVALID]: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: Host: ftp.shopdrawing.co.il. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:cp31.box.co.il
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:387:5)
    at Object.checkServerIdentity (node:tls:354:12)
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1545:27)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:949:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:730:12) {
  reason: "Host: ftp.shopdrawing.co.il. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:cp31.ox.co.il",
  host: 'ftp.shopdrawing.co.il',
  cert: {
    subject: ...,
    issuer: [Object: null prototype] { ... },
    subjectaltname: 'DNS:cp31.box.co.il',
    infoAccess: [Object: null prototype] { ... },
    modulus: '....',
    bits: 2048,
    exponent: '0x10001',
    pubkey: <Buffer 30 82 01 ... >,
    valid_from: 'Mar 24 00:00:00 2023 GMT',
    valid_to: 'Jun 22 23:59:59 2023 GMT',
    fingerprint: '8A:99:3A:xx:xx:......',
    fingerprint256: 'DD:70:5C:xx:xx:......',
    fingerprint512: '4F:84:8A:xx:xx:......',
    serialNumber: '....',
    raw: <Buffer 30 82 05 d2 ... >,
    issuerCertificate: { ... },
    code: 'ERR_TLS_CERT_ALTNAME_INVALID'
  }
}
```

Comment: *"tried to use basic-ftp package"* - please provide the a actual code where you have the problem in nodejs, not only the code where you don't have the problem in other languages. My guess is that you wrongly set "secure" to "implicit".

Comment: @SteffenUllrich updated example

Comment: This is now a totally different error you get - please don't make your question a moving target.

Comment: Solved by `secureOptions: {checkServerIdentity: () => {return null;}}`, but not sure if it's completely correct to disable server name checking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> reason: "Host: ftp.shopdrawing.co.il. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:cp31.ox.co.il",

You are trying to connect to the host with the name "ftp.shopdrawing.co.il". The certificate for the FTP server of the host is for "cp31.ox.co.il" though, which does not match the name you connect to. That's why you get this error.

> Solved by `secureOptions: {checkServerIdentity: () => {return null;}}`, but not sure if it's completely correct to disable server name checking

It is not a good idea to disable even part of the certificate validation. In this case you disable hostname validation, which means that an attacker could use an arbitrary valid certificate issued by a trusted CA to mount a man in the middle attack.

Unfortunately the setup of the FTP server seems to be messed up. The name in the certificate ("cp31.box.co.il") does not resolve to an IP address, so you cannot use this as target instead. The best way is properly to use define a `checkServerIdentity` like you proposed but instead of accepting anything only accept certificates with a specific fingerprint or with a specific subject - see [here](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#certificate-object) for the attributes you can access from the certificate object you get.

For example you can check the subjectaltname:

```
const config = {
    host: "ftp.shopdrawing.co.il",
    ...
    secureOptions: {checkServerIdentity: (name,cert) => {
        if (cert.subjectaltname != "DNS:cp31.box.co.il") {
            return Error("unexpected certificate");
        }
        return null;
    }},
}
```

Or to check for the specific certificate by fingerprint:

```
const config = {
    host: "ftp.shopdrawing.co.il",
    ...
    secureOptions: {checkServerIdentity: (name,cert) => {
        if (cert.fingerprint256 != "DD:70:5C:67:A9:93:C3:08:C5:88:12:E5:80:9B:7C:86:7D:CA:D8:8B:1D:E3:05:66:72:5D:D2:D2:8C:03:15:0A") {
            return Error("unexpected certificate: " + cert.fingerprint256);
        }
        return null;
    }},
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What mean cert `subjectaltname`, and what is the relationship between this server and the certificate issued to another host name. It would be great if you can explain or provide a link for detailed information.

Comment: @rodigy: subject alternative name extension contains the names and IP addresses the certificate is valid for. A certificate authority will check that the one who orders the certificate also owns (or at least controls) the domains the certificate gets issued for.

Comment: could `fingerprint256` change in the future when the certificate is renewed or reissued?

Comment: @rodigy: any change of the certificate (including renewing, reissuing) will result in a changed fingerprint